# What does "milestone" in JSF version context mean?

Tags: jsf, java-ee-6

I'm starting into a new JSF-Webapplicationproject and saw that now there are versions marked with m like 2.2.0-m09 standing for milestone.

The word milestone itself stands for checkpoints which are on the way to a big main goal. But it is not defined if a milestone is something which can be used for production.

What does milestone in jsf version context mean? Is it for productional use?

Comment: The concept itself is used by community in lots of projects. It's related to [software release lifecycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle).

Comment: So this means milestone is a subtype of pre-alpha version in conclusion "don't use it for production!"?

Comment: You're right. Try to use release versions as far as you can for production aims.